# Detect which part of <input type='number'> is clicked?

Tags: html

Is it possible to detect which part of a `<input type='number'>` control is clicked? Or, it there a separate event/property for when the "up/increment" or "down/decrement" part of the control is clicked?

I realize that I can get the "input" event to detect the value, but what I actually need is to detect an increment/decrement when at the min/max. (I'm trying to implement a "looping" behaviour so that a decrement at min takes the control to the max value.)

Comment: Posted an alternate answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76673785/3622569

Answer (score 0):

Are you using javascript? If so you can easily use jquery for this:

```
<input class='fancyClass' 'type='number'>
```

in javascript:

```
$('.fancyClass').on('click', function(){
//Do something
//console.log(this); = gives you the the properties of the object you can use
});
```

/e: You could for example give data-keys to the html field:

```
<input class='fancyClass' 'type='number' data-max='20'>
```

Then in your javascript onclick function you can increase or decrease a variable, and with $(this).data('max') you can decide when to stop doing this and do something, if you want I can write a complete function for you, I do not know at what stage you are.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to watch onChange event and set the min value when max has been reached and the max when the min has been reached.
If you want to be more specific **oninput** is fired when 'up' and 'down' arrows are clicked